# fetching data from JSON string using php * syntax

Tags: php, mediawiki

Here is the JSON array I received:

```
{"parse":{"title":"List of Arrow episodes", "pageid":37371793, "text":{"*":"<div class=\"mw-parser-output\"><h3><span id=\"Season_7_.282018.E2.80.9319.29\"></span><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"Season_7_(2018\u201319)\">Season 7 (2018\u201319)</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span><a href=\"/w/index.php?title=List_of ...}
```

I want to fetch the content under `parse->text->*`, but it's giving me an error.
Here's what I've tried:

```
if ($data = json_decode(@file_get_contents($api_url))) {
    $content = $data->parse->text->*;
    $content = Parser::doTableStuff($content)
    header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo $content;
}
```

After debugging, I identified the problem is in the line `$content = $data->parse->text->*;`
When I tried doing: `$content = $data->parse->text;` it works, so I suspect that the * syntax is not right.

Edit: I tried enclose * with {} and [], but it still giving an error.

Comment: try to use the curly braces, `->{'*'}` like so

Comment: or turn it into an array instead `json_decode(<file get contents>, true)`, then you get an array so you can use `['*']`

Comment: I tried $content = $data[parse][text][*]; and $content = $data->parse->text->{*}; but it still gave me an error (the page is not loading). When I tried $content = $data[parse][text], the webpage loaded.

Comment: Please study the syntax in the duplicate more closely.  You need to use quoting inside the curly braces.  https://3v4l.org/uBR1K Your question will not be reopened because the duplicate provides a perfect resolution.